# How do I get command dotnet to restore?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, terminal, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to create a web app using asp.net core in terminal on MacOS v10.14.5 using yeoman.

dotnet restore
dotnet new restore
dotnet restore new

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   yo update check failed                   │
│            Try running with sudo or get access             │
│            to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/Ezekill/.config │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Ezekills-MacBook-Pro:webapp Ezekill$ ls
MacApp
Ezekills-MacBook-Pro:webapp Ezekill$ cd MacApp
Ezekills-MacBook-Pro:MacApp Ezekill$ ls
Controllers         Program.cs          Views                                           global.json
Data                Properties              appsettings.Development.json    web.config
MacApp.csproj           README.md           appsettings.json            wwwroot
MacApp.db           Services            bower.json
```

Models              Startup.cs          bundleconfig.json
    Ezekills-MacBook-Pro:MacApp Ezekill$ dotnet restore
    A compatible installed dotnet SDK for global.json version: [1.0.0-    rc4-004771] from [/Users/Ezekill/Desktop/webapp/MacApp/global.json]     was not found
    Please install the [1.0.0-rc4-004771] SDK or update   [/Users/Ezekill/Desktop/webapp/MacApp/global.json] with an installed    dotnet SDK:
      2.1.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      2.1.500 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      2.1.505 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      3.0.100-preview5-011568 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
    Ezekills-MacBook-Pro:MacApp Ezekill$ dotnet restore
    A compatible installed dotnet SDK for global.json version: [1.0.0-rc4-004771] from [/Users/Ezekill/Desktop/webapp/MacApp/global.json]  was not found
    Please install the [1.0.0-rc4-004771] SDK or update  [/Users/Ezekill/Desktop/webapp/MacApp/global.json] with an installed  dotnet SDK:
      2.1.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      2.1.500 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      2.1.505 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      3.0.100-preview5-011568 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

To dotnet restore the webapp folder but it throws something about an update or install?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1221 Read the title please.

Answer (score 0):

The yeoman generators for .NET Core are old, very old. It's trying to use .NET Core version `1.0.0-rc4-004771`. I suggest you try and generate a new project using the built-in templates with `dotnet new`.

Comment: How do i go about that? I doing an online udemy course so im getting step by step instructions. Not sure how to go about what you have suggested.

Comment: You should find a new course. That one is apparently *very* outdated. It's using .NET Core 1.0, which is EOL and vastly differs from the current LTS version, 2.1. Yeoman generators is really the least of your problems here. Virtually everything you learn will be wrong, because it doesn't work that way any more.

Comment: Ok thanks you for your advice. I will search for a more resent course.

Comment: You could get started by just typing `dotnet new` in the console and choose a template which you'd like to create.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it..

Instead of using Yeoman to build the wepapp in the webapp folder I used 
command: dotnet new webapp
while in the webapp directory instead of 
command: yo aspnet

Thanks for your help.